# E[(X+Y)^3], where X follows exponential distribution with a, and Y follows exponential distribution with b.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

First, of all, forgive my English terminology. If you need any clarification let me know.

I do understand how E[X+Y] is calculated into E[X]+E[Y], but I'm having trouble when it is ^3.

Also, how can I find φ(x+y)(t)?

Comment: 1. You haven't mentioned the dependence between $X$ and $Y$. (Are they independent?) 2. If they are independent, you can write $E[(X+Y)^3] = E[X^3] + 3 E[X^2] E[Y] + 3 E[X] E[Y^2] + E[Y^3]$ and compute each expectation individually. 3. Compute the expectation $\phi_{X+Y}(t) = E[e^{i(X+Y) t}]$ directly.

Comment: Can you help me calculate E[X^3]? I'm not good with integrals.

Comment: Start with $\int_0^\infty x^3 a e^{-a x} \, dx$ and do [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) three times. (Alternatively if you recognize the [Gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution) you can avoid doing integration by parts.)

Comment: I did, but after the first integration by parts, I need to calculate [-x^3 * e^(-ax)] from 0 to oo, which if I'm not wrong, can't be calculated do to the oo. (forgive me again for the symbols I use, I'm not accustomed to it)

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} x^3 e^{-ax} = 0$. You should review how to compute $E[X]$ and $\text{Var}(X)$ if you are uncomfortable with these computations.